# Discarding Value of OUT Parameter of Procedure in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Is there anyway to ignore the OUT parameter of a procedure?

I have a simple example procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(
            OUT o_result TEXT, 
            OUT o_error TEXT, 
            p_status TEXT)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    p_status = 'do something with this';
    o_result = FALSE;
    o_error= 'error message here';
END;
$$;
```

I always need to o_result out but only sometimes need the error message depending on the situation.

When calling the procedure I have to assign o_error to a variable or I get a SQL error (procedure not found). I've tried using NULL as the outbound variable when I call the procedure but that results in a different SQL error.

This works.

```
CALL my_proc(
    o_result := var1,
    o_error :=  var2,
    p_stats := inbound_var
    );
```

This will say function not found.

```
CALL my_proc(
    o_result := var1,
    p_stats := inbound_var
    );
```

This will cause a SQL error. SQLERRM: procedure parameter "o_error" is an output parameter but corresponding argument is not writable SQLSTATE: 42601

```
CALL my_proc(
    o_result := var1,
    o_error :=  NULL,
    p_stats := inbound_var
    );
```

Is there anyway to ignore the o_error parameter when writing the CALL line, without having to assign a variable to it. Not a major issue just trying to remove some varaibles if not needed.

Comment: Use `RETURNS` instead of `OUT` parameters?

Comment: I can't use `RETURNS` with  as it's a procedure. I also quite like the `CALL` method of calling a procedure rather than having to use `SELECT` for a function just from a style point of view. It's not a major issue but would be nice to just discard return vars that we don't always use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `select` the results of a function, you can use assignment to a variable. This is best handled with a function that returns a user defined type.

```
create type my_result_type as (
       result  text 
     , error   text 
     ) ; 
    
create or replace function get_results (p_stats text) 
    returns  my_result_type 
    language plpgsql
as $$ 
declare
   l_result  my_result_type; 
begin
    l_result.result = 'something done with p_status value';
    l_result.error  = 'error message here';
    return l_result; 
end;
$$;
      

-- test     
do $$ 
declare 
    l_my_resut my_result_type;
begin 
    l_my_resut = get_results (' some parameter'); 
    raise notice 'returned=> result:%, error:%', l_my_resut.result,  l_my_resut.error; 
end;
$$;
```